# Themes for Magento Community Edition?

Tags: magento, themes

Just a quick question, I'm a bit confused.

The only difference between Magento Community Edition and Magento Premium is support, correct?

Are there themes for specific Magento editions, or do all themes work for all editions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [official page of Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/compare) that compares the features of all the different Magento versions.

Most likely themes will work for 90% on all editions, unless they use code that is different between Magento versions.

Comment: Great, that's what i wanted to hear.